# Ensure loading order of components

Tags: javascript, polymer

Using Polymer (0.5.4), I have created a set of components that is used like this:

```
<wrapper-element>
   <child-element></child-element>
</wrapper-element>
```

I need to call a method of the first `child-element` in the wrappers `ready` event/method. Thus, I have to make sure that the child is already initialized when the wrapper is ready.

I found that everything works fine on my local machine if I set the order of the componenet imports like this:

```
<link rel="import" href="child.html">
<link rel="import" href="wrapper.html">
```

Can I depend on this behaviour, though? Is there a way I can make absolutely sure that the child will be available at the time the wrappers ready event fires?

Answer (score 0):

The ready will only be called when parsing the DOM

If you import your htmls like these in the head section, the browser will first load all HTML imports before starting parsing the DOM.

This way, you're safe, but the browser will be blank until all html files are loaded (if you want some faster rendering you'll have to defer the loading of your htmls).

Also, in production environnement, it's usually faster to concatenate your 2 HTML files in a single one (you don't have to bother about dependencies order in that case ;) )